# How do I permit params for my active admin resource with a has_many_through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm having trouble setting my permitted params in active admin. The docs say "Any form field that sends multiple values (such as a HABTM association, or an array attribute) needs to pass an empty array to permit_params". Here is my code from admin/sample.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Sample do
  permit_params :title, :description, :file_type, :audio_data, :channels, :sample_rate, :file_size,
    categories: []
end
```

When I try this all the attributes appear in my active admin table but there is nothing for `categories`. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. I've tried `category_ids` and `sample_categories` too but still it doesn't show in the table. I've also tried adding an attribute to the array, such as `categories: [:name]` but still nothing.

Everything behaves as it should in the app itself and I'm able to add a category when creating a `sample`, for example. Any suggestions about how to solve this? Here is some relevant code.

models/sample.rb

```
class Sample < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :sample_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :sample_categories
end
```

models/category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sample_categories
  has_many :samples, through: :sample_categories
end
```

models/sample_category.rb

```
class SampleCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sample
  belongs_to :category
end
```

controllers/samples_controller.rb

```
...
def sample_params
    params.require(:sample).permit(:title, :description, :audio, :file_type, :file_size, :sample_rate, :channels, :tag_list, category_ids: [])
end
...
```

Comment: If ActiveAdmin is using the collection helpers the parameter is almost surely called `category_ids`. `category_ids: []` will permit [any permitted scalar value](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html). You should be able to check this by either looking at the rendered form or the request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) function in your `Sample` model?

```rb
class Sample < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :sample_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :sample_categories

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end
```

Try first using test or rails console if it works.

Also please update your `admin/sample.rb` to allow [nested attributes](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#nested-resources) from `categories`

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Sample do
  permit_params :title, :description, :file_type, :audio_data, :channels, :sample_rate, :file_size,
    categories_attributes: [:id, :name, :etc]
end
```

Note:
if you are using active admin, the `samples_controller.rb` CRUD controller declaration is not required